# How to handle apollo errors in one place with react-hooks?

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using React with hooks + GraphQL.

My app.jsx:

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
...
const httpLink = ...
const errorLink = onError(err => console.log(err))
const terminatingLink = split(...httpLink, errorLink)
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([terminatingLink])
    ...
})
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <ErrorProvider>
    </ErrorProvider>
</ApolloProvider>
```

Error provider is used as a common state for errors, i.e. if mutation response is bad.
Currently I create onError handler for each(!) mutation and query, i.e. like this:

```
const [createTeam] = useMutation(createTeamQ, {
    onError: (err) => { dispatchError(err) }
})
```

This looks like overcoding, since I do it too often.
But I can't figure out how to dispatch the error in AppolloClient only once in onError() function imported from 'apollo-link-error'. I can't use hooks there.
Should I use redux for this particular case?
Thanks in advance.